# Build Failed for flutter project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, webview

Facing this issue when opening flutter project in Xcode

```
/Users/user/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.2/ios/Classes/webview-umbrella.h: No such file or directory (in target 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps

1. Delete podfile.lock (Do NOT delete PodFile)
2. Delete .symlinks folder
3. Delete pods folder
4. Navigate to ios directory in terminal and run pod install
5. Open the xcworkspace file in xcode
6. Select product -> clean build folder
7. Run the project from xcode once. All subsequent builds should work in your ide